# Rvest extract document range by start/end id

Tags: html, r, rvest

Is it possible to select an extract of an HTML document based on specific start and end points?  For instance:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <p id='fromhere'></p>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <pre id='tohere'></pre>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**R**

```
require(rvest)
require(xml2)
read_html('index.html') %>% get_dom_extract('#fromhere', '#tohere')
```

Does anything like `get_dom_extract` exist, or is it achievable by a combination of methods?  It doesn't seem possible by css selection methods, although I may have missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following idiom will change depending on the way tags are nested. Reference: [node-set intersection](http://sourceware.org/ml/xsl-list/2000-08/msg00355.html):

```
library(rvest)

read_html("<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <p id='fromhere'></p>
    </div>
    <div>this is what we want</div>
    <div>
        <pre id='tohere'></pre>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>") -> pg


html_nodes(pg, xpath="
//*/p[@id='fromhere']/../following-sibling::node()
             [count(.|//*/pre[@id='tohere']/../preceding-sibling::node())
             =
              count(//*/pre[@id='tohere']/../preceding-sibling::node())
             ]           
")
## {xml_nodeset (3)}
## [1] \n    
## [2] <div>this is what we want</div>
## [3] \n
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I make the approach agnostic if e.g. it was not <p> or <pre> elements?  Just remove those tags from the xpath string?

Comment: While making it generic isn't easy (another ref to this type of XML intersection which is dubbed the "Kaysian Method": http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e108) your assertion is correct. You just need to find the proper, unique XPath to the start tag that also lets you obtain `preceding-sibling`s and the proper, unique XPath to the end tag that also lets you obtain it's `preceding-sibling`s.